# TPM Windows Key creation

Tags: windows, encryption, public-key-encryption, tpm

Once Windows has taken ownership of the TPM chip inside my computer is it still possible to create a persistent key inside it ? (Given that I don't have the Owner Password because Windows throws it aways after initializing the TPM).

Is the Storage Root Key (SRK) created by Windows inside the TPM protected with a pin code to perform cipher operations ? If it is where is that password stored in windows ?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who pass by, It is possible.

I did a dual boot with a Windows 10 and an Ubuntu. I put the excellent tools developped here [tpm2-tools](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools) on the Ubuntu and I got to insert my own persistent primary key inside the chip.

The funny/weird thing is that I can create that key and make it persistent under linux (with these tools) also under EFI with a program that I wrote. But under Windows I can't get it to work. I'm going to ask why on another post.